# How to fix 'Fields aren't populating when creating recordset from workbook with two header rows'

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to adjust a vba excel macro that works to collect the data from all workbooks within a specified date range. I'm having difficulty being able to pull in workbooks that have two header rows of strings. When I try to run the macro on these workbooks, the Fields within the Recordset do not populate with the correct information.

The code has previously worked for workbooks with only one header row of strings (with all other data below it being numerical data), but I'm now running into difficulty with workbooks that have two header rows of strings. If I delete one of the 1st 2 rows of strings in the workbook and try running, the macro works fine and the fields populate correctly.. However, this is not a feasible long term solution.

```vb
Dim Header As Boolean
Dim rsCon As Object
Dim rsData As Object
Dim szSQL As String
Dim szConnect As String
Dim sDFolder As String
Dim SourceFile As String

Header = True

'Folder that contains several workbooks
sDFolder = "C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\Test"

'Example File from sDFolder
SourceFile = "Data 2019-02-25.csv"

' Create the connection string
szConnect = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" & _
            "Dbq=" & sDFolder & ";" & _
            "Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;"

' workbook level name
szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & """" & SourceFile & """"

Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rsCon.Open szConnect
rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1   'adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

If Not rsData.EOF Then
    If Header = True Then
        TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
    End If    
End If

rsData.Close
Set rsData = Nothing
rsCon.Close
Set rsCon = Nothing
SetAttr sDFolder, vbNormal
```

The code above works for workbooks with one header, but the Fields in rsData don't populate correctly for workbooks with two headers.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Check to see if the second row is something other than numbers, and if it is then change your `TargetRange` accordingly. (And your `Header` variable is meaningless, because you set it to `True` always, so it (and the test for it later) can both be removed. Your code doesn't do anything if there isn't a header anyway.)

Comment: code tried but could not reproduce (or understand) the problem (only 1st row fetches blank. is it not supposed be normal with larger chunk of numeric data?). may Pl include sample input and output data.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
' First--Open the CSV and detect is there are duplicate Headers
'   If dupes, then copy from line2 forward to the end to a temp file
'   At end, delete the original file, and rename temp to original name

Sub RemoveDuplicateHeader(strPath As String, strFile As String)
    ' open the csv file
    f1 = FreeFile
    Open strPath & strFile For Input As #f1 ' Open file for input

    Line Input #f1, line1
    Line Input #f1, strLine

    ' If there are duplicate Header rows, then remove one
    If line1 = strLine Then
        f2 = FreeFile
        Open strPath & "Temp_" & strFile For Output As #f2
            Print #f2, strLine
        Do While Not EOF(f1)
            Line Input #f1, strLine
            Print #f2, strLine
        Loop
        Close #f1 ' Close file
        Close #f2

        If Dir(strPath & "Temp_" & strFile) <> "" Then
            Kill strPath & strFile
            Name strPath & "Temp_" & strFile As strPath & strFile
        End If

    Else
        Close #f1 ' Close file

    End If

End Sub
```